# Spring Boot JVM Arguments Work on Command Line, Not in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have a project which, when run from inside Spring Tool Suite (both Eclipse and VS Code) refuses to see defined JVM parameters, but when run from the command-line via `spring-boot:run` sees them fine. So, the problem seems to be within the editor.

Here's the snippet from the `pom.xml`:

```xml
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <jvmArguments>
                                -Dspring.boot.debug 
                                -DEXTERNAL_PROPS=C:/myapp/myapp.properties 
                                -DENCRYPTOR_SECRET=password
                            </jvmArguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

Can someone assist so that I can get these working inside the editor?

Comment: seems: sts does not use much of the maven/gradle infrastructure when running as "Spring Boot App" (which is default, when hitting the "play button" for a quickstart spring-boot app). (When this setup works in other environments,) You could get more lucky with a "Maven Build"(/"Gradle Task") (Run)  configuration..

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse as well as VSCode you can add those JVM arguments to the so-called launch configurations. In Eclipse, you can find them via the drop-down from the Run button, in VSCode you can get to them by opening the `launch.json` file.